# Empty response from curl php upload

Tags: php, curl, upload

I'm constructing a multi file upload in php with curl.
However, I keep getting back empty responses from the server I'm posting data to. The files are sent to this php script via ajax, inside a files array. I know the file exists, and that the token works. However I haven't been able to get back any favorable responses.

```
 $curl_options = '';

 $curl_data = array(array());
 $curl_data[0]["post"] = array();
 $curl_data[0]["post"]["folderid"] = 1568663;
 $curl_data[0]["post"]["file"] ='@'.$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];
 $curl_data[0]["post"]["filename"] =$_FILES['files']['name'][0];


function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {
$access_token = $_POST["token"];
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer   {$access_token}");
 $url = 'https://apiv2.webdamdb.com/uploads';

  $curly = array();

  $result = array();


  $mh = curl_multi_init();

   foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

   $curly[$id] = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt_array($curly[$id],array(   
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>  $headers,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $d["post"]));

   if (!empty($options)) {
   curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
   }
   curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
   }

   $running = null;
   do {
   $resp = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);

  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  curl_multi_close($mh);
  print_r($data);
  print_r($curly);
  print_r($result);
  return $result;
   }

  multiRequest($curl_data,$curl_options);
```